# zabbix sla report

Tags: zabbix, report

Стоит задача мониторить уровень доступности определенной услуги. В расчетах должны учитываться только триггеры в состояниях High и Disaster.

Настроены Parent Service (настройки на первом скрине) и два Child Services (второй скрин):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде все верно. Но если выводить SLA Report, то данные по Downtime в нем будут значительно выше, чем реальное время сколько триггеры в состояниях High и Disaster были в активном состоянии за определенный промежуток времени.
И отсюда вопрос как zabbix высчитывает состояния Error budget и Downtime? И не учитываются ли в данном случае для расчета уровня доступности все триггеры, а не только High и Disaster?
Так же хочу отметить, что problem tags вешались на конкретные хосты, а не на триггеры.